# Creating model in django and overriring django-redux

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create a model in django(1.11). I am using django-redux for registration. After user log in, it will ask some details about the user and that will be saved inside database. Below is my code but nothing is there inside db. It should be a seperate model:

```
    from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.
    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        name = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
        email = models.EmailField('auth.User.email')
        mob_number = models.IntegerField()
        address = models.TextField()

        def __init__(self):
            return self.name
```

Comment: I don't think you've given enough information to explain the problem. However you should definitely remove the `__init__` method. You shouldn't usually have to override `__init__` for Django models, and doing `return self.name` is definitely wrong - that looks more like what you'd do in the `__str__` method.

Comment: Why you use `__init__()`  ?

Comment: Yeah I was wrongly using __init__().

Comment: What I want is I have already used django-registration-redux method to authenticate user. Now after user log in in my site, I want them to fill up a form for more details. for that I want a separate model like class UserProfile(models.Model). How to achieve that? What packages I need to import? Pls provide full code if psbl..Thank you..